# MacOS Terminal with path and file colors

Tags: macos, colors, terminal, filebeat

I just saw a video about to [get started with Filebeat](https://www.elastic.co/videos/getting-started-with-filebeat), and the guy is using a nice terminal with colored paths and files.

[image: Terminal]

I very loved it, looked everywhere in the internet, but didn't find the terminal he is using.

Is there anyone here who knows the name of this terminal ?

Comment: Probably not (several terminals can do this, including Terminal.app and iTerm / iTerm2).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He is probably using iTerm2 (https://www.iterm2.com/) with a custom scheme (https://github.com/mbadolato/iTerm2-Color-Schemes) and powerline (https://github.com/powerline/powerline)

Comment: Thank you very much, I followed your links and found what I was looking for :)

Comment: You are very welcome. You can really go crazy with customizing your terminal